# Unable to Render a FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to render a FlatList but I don't see it on the Screen

I get my Data of my Reducer through a Console Log and in the Console I get the correct Data:

```
User {
  "apellido": "Alas",
  "correo": "prueba@uno.com",
  "id": 2021-02-08T23:52:58.855Z,
  "nombre": "Rene",
  "telefono": "72457183",
}
```

Here is my Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import UserItem from "../components/UserItem";

export default function Page2() {
    const users = useSelector(state => state.registro.availableUsers);

    console.log(users);

    if (users.length === 0) {
        return <View style={styles.centered} >
            <Text>No Existen Usuarios</Text>
        </View>
    }

    return (
        <FlatList
        data={users}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={
            itemData => <UserItem
                nombre={itemData.item.nombre}
                apellido={itemData.item.apellido}
                telefono={itemData.item.telefono}
                coreo={itemData.item.coreo}
                onSelect={() => { }}
            />
        }
    />
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9fafd',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    }
});
```

As you can see the Console Log shows there is data being Received from the Reducer, but there is no data displayed through the FlatList

As you can see in the Picture

[image]

I tried to get to the same Result (Render a List) with the MAP function but still getting an Error:

***TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...users.map...')***

Although I know there shouldn't be an Undefined as there is that printed to the Console

Any Ideas?

PS. I think the Issue might be with the Action or Reducer:

***Action***

```
//Import Model
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import User from '../../models/user';

//Constant Creation 
export const REGISTER = 'REGISTER';

export const createUser = (nombre, apellido, telefono, correo) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        console.log('entra a fun');
        try{
            console.log('antes de crear');
            const createdUser = new User(new Date(), nombre, apellido, telefono, correo);
            console.log('despues de crear');
            console.log(createUser);

            dispatch({type: REGISTER, user: createdUser});
        }
        catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
};
```

***Reducer***

```
import { REGISTER } from '../actions/registro';

const initialState = {
    availableUsers: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER:
            return {
                ...state,
                availableUsers: action.user,
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: FYI the ID is a just the DATE() function as just needed an ID

Comment: What you posted in your first console.log example is just one user -- are you positive that it's an array of users?

Comment: I just tested with a single user but it is an array

Comment: Okay -- just asking because your `TypeError` suggests differently -- map would be undefined on something that wasn't an array.

Comment: I see your point, I think it might be my Action or Reducer:

Comment: Hey @jnpdx I added the Action and the Reducer, I believe that I just add the single Object to the Array of Available Users and it doesn't push new objects in, any idea on how to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your available users is just getting one user, instead of updating/appending the new one.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER:
            return {
                ...state,
                availableUsers: [...state.availableUsers, action.user],
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

By spreading (...) `state.availableUsers`, you can append the new user to the end of the existing array.

Comment: It work now this might be to much but if I need to delete one of those items inside the reducer, any ideas?

Comment: You mean delete one of the users?

Comment: Yes i need to delete ond of the users inside the availableUsers array through the id

Comment: Something like `availableUsers: state.availableUsers.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)` (I'm making assumptions about how `User` is structured and how the `Action` would be defined).